# Cross-thread problems with .NET data binding

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, data-binding

I have a number of Windows Forms controls which are used to interact with my program objects. Currently they subscribe to an "Updated" event on the object and manually update values when needed. I would like to replace all (or as much as possible) of this boilerplate code using data binding.

The problem I'm running into is that the object state can be modified by any one of several different threads at any moment. Currently I use Invoke() to handle this, which works fine, but when I switch to data binding I get swamped by illegal cross-thread control exceptions. Is there a preferred method to handle this gracefully using data binding, or am I better off just leaving things the way they are now?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your before and after code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are data binding your controls to the data sources that are being updated from the underlying thread, then you will have to move the code that does the updating to the UI thread through a call to [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.invoke.aspx).

Or, if you want, you *could* get a [`ISynchronizeInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx) implementation (or a [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx)) and have all the events fire on the UI thread.  Of course, this could cause unintended problems with your code, as you weren't firing the events on the UI thread in the first place.

Comment: +1 for using a `SynchronizationContext` -- as you mention it may identify unknown issues, but cleaning up threading errors is rarely a bad idea